# How to make a tab header with only an icon and translucent components using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-7

I want to make a tabbed pane in my Swing GUI such that the tab headers appear as icons (i.e. I want to place a picture on the tabbed pane headers, like we can place pictures on buttons)

A GUI with tabbed pane headers appearing as icons (only pictures on those headers are visible, rest of the entire component is completely transparent), and when the user clicks on a picture/icon/tabbed pane header, the entire tabbed pane becomes translucent, and displays its contents (like text). The pictures attached show it better. *Please note that there are no visible borders of the tabbed pane.*

**Is it possible? Any tips or suggestions are welcome?**

Moreover, **are such transparent and translucent swing components possible through the drag and drop facility of the NetBeans IDE?**

[image]

When the user clicks:

[image]

**I will be thankful for any ideas on how to do this.**

---

[image]

Comment: yes it's possible... what have you tried? show us your code.

Comment: it may also be worth looking into using `JavaFX` - the new UI toolkit that replaces/supersedes Swing in Java 8. Making modern UI's is much easier and faster in JavaFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the tabs use `addTab(null, icon, component)` of `JTabbedPane` with `icon` the image you want and `component` a translucent `JLabel`. You can make one by calling its `setOpaque(true)` and `setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 100))`.

**Edit**

Try to run this and see if it's getting closer to what you want.

```
public class TransparentTabs extends JFrame {

    private final static Color TRANSPARENT = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

    TransparentTabs() {

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Text Here");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(TRANSPARENT);

        tabs.addTab(null, new ImageIcon("path to image"), label); // Change path
        tabs.addTab("Tab to the left has only an image", new JLabel("Something"));
        tabs.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED); // Placeholder for background image
        getContentPane().add(tabs);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", TRANSPARENT);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", TRANSPARENT);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background", TRANSPARENT);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", TRANSPARENT);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", TRANSPARENT);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", TRANSPARENT);

        new TransparentTabs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify what does "and component a translucent JLabel." mean? Does it mean I have to add a JLabel inside the tabbed pane?

Comment: @Zarah A tab in a `JTabbedPane` consists of the "header" and the "component it displays". You need to create a `JLabel` and pass it as an argument to the `addTab` method. I suggest you try to write some code and post it so we can better address your problems.

Comment: Can't I do it with the Netbeans GUI builder?

Comment: @Zarah I don't know, I don't use NetBeans nor a GUI builder.

Comment: Then I have to understand some code and then write my code to do it. Before I set to it, can you please confirm me that (1) What I wanted to ask in the question above was that the tabs should look just like icons (only the icon in the header should be visible, the component should be invisible) (2) When the user clicks on an icon, the tab's translucent body opens/displays. I am still doubtful if I made my point clear. So I still want to confirm, is that possible?

Comment: (1) I actually want the "text here" and "something" to appear only when the user clicks on the tab's header. (2) I do not want the boundaries of the tabbed pane to be visible.

Comment: @Zarah (1) Already happens. (2) You mean the borders of the tab headers? Right now there are no borders for the tabbed pane, it is the only component in the frame.

Comment: (1) Please see the screenshot I just posted. I did not click anywhere inside that window, but I can still see `Text Here`... In the images I had initially posted, see in the first image, you can only see 4 icons on the background (because the entire tabbed pane is transparent, you can't see any trace of it), now see in the second image when the user clicks the first icon (which is actually the header of the tabbed pane), the translucent component of the tabbed pane's header gets apparent (with its text on it). Please tell me if I can do that.

Comment: 2. You can see the kinda white or light blue colored thin line around the top and sides of the tab headers (because of which you know where the tab header starts and where it ends) - I am calling it the border in simple speak, I don't know what it is. Let's say it is a tabbed pane delimiter kinda thing, I don't want it.

Comment: @Zarah While you can remove the borders around the tab headers, the user will have no indication of what is the selectable area for the header or which tab is selected. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, The users will see the icons on the headers and click them.

Comment: @Zarah But the users will not know which is currently selected. Try now the new code.

Comment: I am confused now. Actually the working is that there are 6 buttons. When the user clicks on each one of them, a list (different for all 6 buttons) will be displayed. The user can select an item from the list, and then the information about that item will be displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51553/discussion-between-user1803551-and-zarah)